# xpages: how to retrieve the data from various views and process the data?

Tags: xpages

I would like to ask how to retrieve the data from various views and process those data in xpages?

We are developing a web application (xpages) using domino designer 8.5.2.

We search on the internet and find books to think the solution, however the result is not really fulfill the task objective. Therefore I would like to seek your advice please.

One of our task is display data like this:

[image]

Before I start to design in Lotus Domino Designer, I have the following thoughts:

A view to store a list of activities: e.g.  Activity 1, Activity 2, Activity 3, Activity 4, Activity 5, etc.

A view to store a list of group: e.g.   Group A, Group B, Group C, Group D, etc.

A view to store a list of member: e.g.  people

A view to store a list of group member: e.g.  Group + people

A view to store a list of activity member: e.g.  Activity + people

After I have those views, I decide to divide into several parts to fulfill the requirement

1. Display a list of activities.
2. Display the appropriate group (choose by user) with relevant data.
3. Find the total number that how many people in a group .
4. Find the total number that people in relevant group joined each activity.
5. Get the percentage of each activity for the group joined.

Here is the question. How to retrieve the data from various views and process those data?

I think it may be hard to do, so I am seeking a simple way to achieve the goal.

So far as I know, a view is used to store data and if I need to retrieve data, I need to use data binding and use formula like @DbColumn to get the appropriate data.

But those methods are used to retrieve the raw data from a view only. We are trying to process the data after the data is retrieved from a view.

I have an idea that is to use computed field and start the experiment (I pasted the code below for your advice please).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Activities" id="label11"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label id="label3"></xp:label></xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Group" id="label1"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label value="Percentage" id="label2"></xp:label>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField6"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "Group A"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view
//the following code is sample only
return "Activity 1"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField7"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "3"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>/<xp:text escape="true"     id="computedField8"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from  a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "10"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField17"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should process the data and show the result
//the following code is sample only
return "30%"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view
//the following code is sample only
return "Activity 2"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField9"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "5"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>/<xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField10"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "10"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField18"><xp:this.value><! [CDATA[#{javascript://should process the data and show the result
//the following code is sample only
return "50%"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>

            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view
//the following code is sample only
return "Activity 3"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField11"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "6"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>/<xp:text escape="true"  id="computedField12"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "10"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField19"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should process the data and show the result
//the following code is sample only
return "60%"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>

            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view
//the following code is sample only
return "Activity 4"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField13"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "9"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>/<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField14"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "10"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField20"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should process the data and show the result
//the following code is sample only
return "90%"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view
//the following code is sample only
return "Activity 5"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField15"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "1"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>/<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField16"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should retrieve from a view and process the data
//the following code is sample only
return "10"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
        <xp:td></xp:td>
        <xp:td><xp:text escape="true" id="computedField21"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://should process the data and show the result
//the following code is sample only
return "10%"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Those code is just the idea from the requirement, I am still thinking how to process the data from a view.

I am grateful if someone can give advice on this issue please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, my first advice upgrade to 9.0.1. Second advice, have a look a closer look at Java. You could just build a data class (Java Bean) to hold all your columns. Collect your infos from different views in the backend and pass a Vector to a datacontext, which is then displayed in a repeat or view control.

Comment: Hello @umeli, thanks for your comment. I am sorry to ask how to use java bean in xpages? It is because in Lotus Domino Designer, I cannot find a tool that allows me to input java code.

Comment: Hi, that's why I recommended the upgrade. I think starting with 8.5.3 it is under Code/Java in the designer. And there are loads of tutorials in the net... http://de.slideshare.net/RussellMaher/jmp402 or https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XFXEmXH8KFcXEHcs2qvbWqOs_TqJWJ8Dbs9CMMKLszI/mobilebasic?pli=1

Comment: Hello @umeli, thanks for your reply. I just found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mluKE-twx8s , it is about java in domino designer, I tried to do the steps to enable java in designer but failed. Recall to your comment, the problem is the version of the designer.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but may I ask is no anyone use Domino Designer 8.5.2 to develop web application now, right?

Comment: I would like ask a question about the version of Domino Designer please. Assume we upgrade the Domino Designer to version 8.5.3, and we shall able to write java code or use Apache POI 4, is this concept correct? We develop a web application to the user. But the user does not have Domino Designer and only have IBM Lotus Notes 8.5.2 for send/receive emails, so can the user use the web application that designed with different versions? Thank you

Comment: If you only do web applications, then the Domino versions have to match. In 8.5.2 the java code is only accessible in the package explorer view. (see point 2.2 /2.3 https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Java_Control_in_an_NSF#Open+the+Package+Explorer+view ).

Comment: Thank you so much @umeli. The website is useful. I follow the instruction step by step and hopefully it can help me(our team) to complete the task. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate for it.